# Code First Migrations generates NTEXT instead of nvarchar in SQL Server CE

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I have started introducing code first migrations in the project, however I have stumbled upon several issues I am not able to resolve.

The setup is, that the project has two targets: an online client, which connects to a WCF service and uses a regular SQL Server database. Also included is an offline client, which holds all data locally and uses a SQL Server CE database.

This already works. Now I need to introduce a way to migrate both database versions. Of course I would prefer using the same migrations code. What I have done so far, is:

- `enable-migrations` (using a localhost SQL Server db, where I create the migrations against)
- `add-migration` (for the initial migration)

One problem is that when I create my SQL Server CE database using `CreateIfNotExists` initializer, the db will be created with all string properties mapped to `nvarchar` columns.

However, when I start using migrations, and create my db with a `MigrateToLatestVersion` initializer, the db will created, but the string properties are now mapped to `NTEXT` columns.

A subsequent seed fails, because I get the following exception:

> The ntext and image data types cannot be used in WHERE, HAVING, GROUP BY, ON, or IN clauses, except when these data types are used with the LIKE or IS NULL predicates.

I have tried to force the model builder to use `nvarchar` for strings, but to no avail. It is completely ignored.

```
modelBuilder.Properties<string>().Configure(config => config.HasColumnType("nvarchar"));
```

I am kind of lost here really.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution and it is rather embarrasing, really.

I forgot to recreate my initial migration, after i added my modelbuilder code for the string properties.

I just recreated it now and it works.